# Varying Order of Covariant Differentiation

Tags: tensors

Does the order of covariant differentiation matter?

Will   E$_i$$_j$,$_k$$_l$$_t$ =E$_i$$_j$,$_l$$_t$$_k$ ?

Does it matter if the tensor E$_i$$_j$ is continuously differentiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the order does matter, in just the way that the order of taking mixed partial derivatives matters, at least for functions whose partials exists but whose total derivative does not (a property usually due to non-commuting of the partials!).

Take some such example -- which you can look up in most multivariable calculus books -- and you can build your tensor example. Call the example $x, y \mapsto f(x, y)$.

Now build $E$: First, you can say that there's just one component, $E_{11}$, since $ij$ have no bearing on your question. Then make $E(x, y, z)$ be simply $z \cdot f(x, y)$. Look at 
$$
E_{x,y,z} \\
E_{y, z, x}
$$
The first will be $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$, the second will be $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$. These will then be distinct for some $(x, y)$, because $f$ is a function chosen to have unequal mixed partials at some point.

If, on the other hand, everything in sight is infinitely continuously differentiable, then all such examples fly out the window, and reordering the derivatives will be fine.

Comment: So, if I have a continuously differentiable tensor, then, the order does not matter irrespective of the type of manifold it is in?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the type of manifold", so I can't answer this. Can you clarify?

Comment: This might be off-topic but what I want to prove is this identity,

Comment: Ummm.... *which* identity would that be?

Comment: C$_i$$_j$$_k$$_l$,$_t$+C$_j$$_k$$_l$$_t$,$_i$ + C$_k$$_l$$_t$$_i$,$_j$ + C$_l$$_t$$_i$$_j$,$_k$+C$_t$$_i$$_j$$_k$,$_l$= zero

, C$_i$$_j$$_k$$_l$= D$_i$$_j$$_k$,$_l$ + D$_j$$_k$$_l$,$_i$ + D$_k$$_l$$_i$,$_j$ + D$_l$$_i$$_j$,$_k$ and



C$_i$$_j$$_k$$_l$ is the curl of D$_i$$_j$$_k$
also,
D$_i$$_j$$_k$= -D$_j$$_i$$_k$=-D$_i$$_k$$_j$=-D$_k$$_j$$_i$

Comment: The identity above where D$_i$$_j$$_k$ is the curl of a symmetric rank two tensor. So, when I try to prove this by expanding the covariant derivatives, I get a big mess with nothing cancelling out. That is why I wanted  to know if the order of indices could be manipulated to help cancellation.

Comment: Well...if you assume enough degrees of continuity and differentiability -- say $C^\infty$, then you should be OK. But as for this particular identity: I have no idea whether it's true or not...I can merely say that if everything is assumed smooth, then swapping the order of differentiation is OK, precisely because it's OK in Euclidean space.

Comment: The thing is, I ran a Ricci contraction and brought it down to a form where I have a curl of curl of a rank two symmetric tensor. The rank 2 tensor is the strain rate tensor. So, for a smooth manifold, the double curl vanishes. If I want that identity to hold in curved space, can I just say the double curl does not vanish( not equal to zero) and move on? Will that be correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29400/discussion-between-nihal-and-john-hughes).

Comment: Sorry for that. I messed up my concepts. Guess I have to start learning again. Thanks for clearing things up!

Comment: @Ismail Bello: Hello, thanks for that compatibility insight. I didn't see it myself . I don't use any one book. I just read pdfs and excerpts on the net and sometimes, Wikipedia articles.

Answer (score 0):

In general no, for example on a reimannian manifold where the christoffel symbols and its derivatives do not vanish there is a loss in commutativity:

$$\nabla_a \nabla_bT^c \ne \nabla_b \nabla_aT^c$$

infact:

$$\nabla_a \nabla_bT^c - \nabla_b \nabla_aT^c = R^{c}_{dab}T^d$$

Where $R$ is called the reimann christoffel tensor. It has a beautiful story which you can find by searching for it in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) along with a more geometric picture as a preamble to the concept of curvature.

In a euclidean space  this is not the case as the mixed partial derivatives are equal and the components of $R$ vanish.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_(mechanics)

Comment: Check the above article out and refer compatibility of infinitesimal strains where it mentions something about an omega tensor being continuously differentiable

Comment: Ah, I see, so the compatibility conditions for infinitesimal strains is the requirement that 2 times covariant differentiation (i.e $[\nabla_a \nabla_b - \nabla_b \nabla_a]\omega_{cd}$) of the omega tensor will vanish. Therefore the order doesnt matter if compatibility holds. In the same article it says for finite strains as well, compatibility requires the Riemann christoffel tensor to vanish. Interesting, I didnt know that about compatibility. What book are you using?

Comment: I would assume differentiability is inferred yes? Otherwise we will be forced to rethink the meaning of the expressions yes? @JohnHughes do you agree?

Comment: I think of $E_{,i}$ as meaning "the partial derivative of $E$ with respect to the $i$th variable." Such partials can exist without the function $E$ being differentiable, or can exist, and have $E$ be differentiable, but *not* have the derivative continuous. (Which is why we have names like $C^1$, etc.) Your claim that "mixed partials are equal" just isn't true, unless you add further constraints like "existence of derivative" (and perhaps continuity, too...I forget!) rather than mere "existence of partials".